# Stretch a UV Map In Sync WIth A Shape Key?

Tags: animation, texturing, shape-keys, pose-mode

I have a Minecraft rig set up so that the arm/leg will keep a 90 degree angle so that the leg doesn't deform at the joint.  I did this using a shape key with a drive.

The problem with this is that it causes the texture to deform when the shape key is used.
Is there a way I can make the UV Map stretch in sync with the shape key drive so that it does not deform the texture?  Am I approaching this wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you illustrate a little further? You would expect a UV texture to stick to the skin of a deforming object.. it's unclear what is happening, that you don't want.

Comment: I'm going to rewrite the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a UV map would stretch with the mesh.
If you want some block based (alike non deforming lego) character.
Then you create it as separate blocks,
ea : upper leg is a cube and lower leg is a seperate cube.

For each cube part you set the bone weight 100% it will not deform, and from start to end move with the bone, as such the UV (now per block) does not get deformed.

Its a bit hard to tell if you want such movement, i took a little bit of imagination with your problem description, trying to follow what you want.
Its quite common here to put in the blend file in your question, its not required but just a sugestion.